# Editing a UITableView with a button from another view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delete-row, editing

I have two views, one with a button where I want when the button is pressed to get the other view with a UITableView to be in a Editing mode.
Here is my code, the editing works when I put the second view code in `viewDidLoad`but dosent work when I call it from the first view.

First View Code:

```
@IBAction func addButtClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let vc = GrowthMainViewController()
    vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    vc.editbuttpressed()     

}
```

Second View (with the tableView) code:

```
 func editbuttpressed() {

    self.scheduleTableView.isEditing = true
    self.goalsTableView.isEditing = true

}
```

Comment: If you want to send me your project I could take a look. It could be caused by the second view not yet being in memory.

Comment: How are `ScheduleTableView` and `GoalsTableView` initialized?

Comment: @CaseyWest Thanks, I sent you the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue arises from trying to access a tableView that is an IBOutlet. The destination view controller's outlets is not created yet which that's why all IBOutlets would be nil.

The resolution for this was to create a boolean variable in the destination view...

```
var tempBoolean: Bool? = false
```

You can then assign that variable's value to true in the first viewController, which will work because it is initialized with a value.

Finally, in your destination view enable editing depending on that boolean variable's value in viewDidLoad...

```
if (tempBoolean == true) { 
   scheduleTableView.isEditing = true
   goalsTableView.isEditing = true
}
```

Something along those lines resolve this issue.